# How do I fix "incompatible type" that's happening with my exceptions code?

Tags: java

Everytime I try to compile my Cirlce class I get an "incompatible type" error message highlighting "ShapeException" What do I need to do to get rid of this error?

Circle class

```
   public Circle(double inRadius )throws ShapeException{ //THE EXCEPTION NAME HIGHLIGHTS
    if(inRadius <= 0.0)
    {
        throw new ShapeException("ShapeException occurred...");
    }
    radius = inRadius;
```

Could the problem be linked to my super/subclasses?

```
  public class Exception
 {
   public Exception(String msg)
   {

   }
 }
```

Subclass:

```
    public class ShapeException extends Exception
    {
     public ShapeException(String msg)
    {
      super(msg);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Did you define your _own_ `Exception` class?  They must be "real" exceptions, descended from `java.lang.Throwable`.

Comment: @rgettman your home-made exceptions should extend from `Exception`, `RuntimeException` or another descendant of `Exception`, but not directly from `Throwable` (sadly, I cannot remove my upvote from your comment).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza True, but strictly speaking, any `Throwable` can be in the `throw` and `throws` clauses.  So, it _must_ be a `Throwable`, and it _should_ be descended from `RuntimeException` or another `Exception`.

Comment: @rgettman strictly speaking, only descendants of `Throwable` can be used in `throw` **but** your own exceptions should not extend directly from `Throwable`, the fact *you can* doesn't mean *you should*.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes; I think we're saying the same thing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `ShapeException` extends the REAL `Exception` class (that is, `java.lang.Exception`), not your made-up one. Best thing to do is just to get rid of your made up `Exception` class

Comment: I have to make up my own exception class. This is a homework I'm working on and I'm specifically told to make an Exceptions class...

Comment: @user2840682 then tell your professor/teacher to come here and ask a question about *How my students should implement their own Exception that will confuse them with `java.lang.Exception`?* Also, ask your professor/teacher if you also should create your own `String` class.

Comment: Your `ShapeException` IS an exception class.  Just do NOT make a class called `Exception`.  Ever.

Answer (score -1):

I was also getting incompatible types exception can't convert to java.lang.Throwable
error while building application though I extended my custom class from RuntimeException class in Intellij. It was compilation issue. Please clean and build your project then try it will work.